# Strategy to manage Redis collections in Java

Tags: java, nosql, redis, spring-data-redis

I have a web application where I use a relational database and Redis for storing my key/value pairs. I am using Spring Data Redis in my DAO methods to access Redis collections. The problem is that having many Redis collections in the application makes it really difficult to manage them. I believe that each collection should be accessed from one single place only i.e writes and reads for one collection should be centralized, but that is not the case in my app currently. So I would like to come up with a proper and encapsulated access mechanism for all my Redis collections.

How should I structure my app to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate` class. a generic template to access all redis provided data structure

Comment: I am already using RedisTemplate but it doesn't provide safe and centralized access to collections.

Answer (score 0):

Create classes which deals with only one entity at a time. For example, if you have domain objects Users and Posts (for a Twitter clone example), you can create UserRepository and PostRepository each dealing with their own entities.
UserRepository deals with adding users, deleting users, updating user details and so on. And PostRepository does so for posts. You can use these repositories in service classes to achieve business functions.